# A class with two types and a single get

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class `A` that has two constructors, one for `float` and another one for `double`. It also has a single method that can return either, depending on the type argument.

This is my attempt.

```cs
public class A {
    private readonly float fooV1;
    private readonly double fooV2;

    public A(float foo) { this.fooV1 = foo; }
    public A(double foo) { this.fooV2 = foo; }

    public T GetFoo<T>() {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(float)) { return (dynamic)this.fooV1; }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(double)) { return (dynamic)this.fooV2; }
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

First of all, this isn't type safe, so it ends up crashing when I call the wrong type. Additionally, I have to cast to `dynamic` since I can't cast to `T`.

Is there a smarter and more type-safe approach?

P.S. this question is inspired by Unity.

Comment: Doing this type of thing `== typeof` in a generic method is usually a sign generics are the wrong tool for the job

Comment: @viveknuna I tried doing so just now, because I have no clue what that should do. It doesn't seem to help. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: @TheGeneral I know I'm doing something wrong, because this seems very wrong, but I still don't know of any better way of doing this. What's the best approach, if not generics?

Comment: @viveknuna, I just tried removing the dynamic cast after adding the type restriction and I got the following error: "Cannot convert expression type `Cannot convert expression type 'float' to return type 'T'`.

Comment: Soo.. what's the overall aim here? What thing has a gun to your head forcing you to provide this GetFoo?

Comment: @CaiusJard hahhahahaha just curiosity on how Unity manages to do so and even add code completion. If it has code completion then it means it's safe at compile time, no error throwing.

Comment: [Unity's source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hoodwink the compiler to say you know better by just casting it to object I guess `(T)(object)`,

```
public T GetFoo<T>() {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(float)) { return (T)(object)this.fooV1; }
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(double)) { return (T)(object)this.fooV2; }
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

You could get creative with the use of an operators, which will save the type being boxed or the use of a *dynamic*

```
public static implicit operator float(A a) => a.fooV1;
public static implicit operator double(A a) => a.fooV2;
```

Note : you could also do this the other way as well..

However, what you are doing is not really a good look, nothing will ever be compile time type safe and will always have the potential to produce runtime error or hard to understand problems, you should likely rethink your problem unfortunately

Comment: I'll keep this in mind. As a question of curiosity, how does Unity implement this? Is it because they compile things differently?

Comment: @JaackoTorus This is just standard C#, i am not sure how the unity AOT compilers deal with operators, though I couldn't image it be much of a problem, it would be more performant than any dynamic or boxing exercise (id imagine)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(T)Convert.ChangeType(this.fooV1, typeof(T))`. Check complete code below.

```
public class A {
private readonly float fooV1;
private readonly double fooV2;

public A(float foo) { this.fooV1 = foo; }
public A(double foo) { this.fooV2 = foo; }

public T GetFoo<T>() {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(float)) { return (T)Convert.ChangeType(this.fooV1, typeof(T)); }
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(double)) { return (T)Convert.ChangeType(this.fooV2, typeof(T)); }
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: Meh, you might as well just save the hassle of Convert going round the houses to box it up and do `return(T)(object)fooVwhatever`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this could work

```cs
public dynamic GetFoo<T>()
{
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(float)) { return fooV1; }
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(double)) { return fooV2; }
  return new {};
}
float f = GetFoo<float>();
```